# Images get blurred in my magento theme homepage

Tags: css, image, magento, themes, e-commerce

I am new to magento. I am using a theme 'rwd'. The product images get blurred when its listed on home page.

With Inspect element, I found that its natural image size is 85x85. But re-sized to 140x140. How do i set the image to 140x140 or any other procedure to be taken care for image resolutions?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking : you found the image is resized to 140x140 yet you ask how to set it to 140x140?.. well it's already the case no? Please describe your problem. Please also specify if you need a css solution to your problem or anything else.

Comment: The actual size of the thumbnail image showing is cropped to 85x85px. But the CSS of the image place holder is showing 140x140px. So the image is resized to 140x140px and loss in clarity. Now i need to set the cropped thumbnail from 85x85px to 140x140px.

Comment: Are your original images in 85x85 or is it something magento does for you?

Comment: Original images are around 1350x1000px. I am not able to track where these thumbnail images dimensions are defined inside magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

Go to the file `view.xml` which you can find in `code/Magento/Catalog/etc/`.

Open the file and edit line 31 from :

```
<var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">85</var>
```

to :

```
<var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">140</var>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside the template file:

`app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`

you will find around line 128 (Magento 1.9.1.x) the image size setting for the Grid View:

```
<?php $_imgSize = 85; ?>
```

just change the value to the one you need. After clearing Magento image cache you will find that the small images will be created at the resolution you set, thus not involving the poor browser resize.

In .phtml files there are many of these `$_imgSize` settings related to the different views, just do a text search for the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case is the uploaded image size is smaller and in default magento resizes product image to 140x140.So in this case the image tends to expand and hence it looks blurr.

One solution would be to upload an image with large size.

Comment: Ya. But the image I upload have around 1350x1000px in dimension.

Comment: I am not able to track where these thumbnail images dimensions are defined.

Comment: enable the template path hint to find out the exact phtml file and then serch for something like this.                        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
->constrainOnly(TRUE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize(600,null)
?>
Here 6oo determines the width

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open the magento project with a good text editing software such as [sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), and then do a research in the whole project `(ctrl + alt + F)`, and look for the string `'140'`.

That way you may find the place where magendo defines the size to which magendo resizes your image.

Comment: Code search can be done on [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=140). As you can see, `140` is used in many places.